# NSDocument subclass "close" method called twice

Tags: cocoa, nsdocument

I have a document-based Cocoa application which subclasses `NSDocument` as `MyDocument`.  Each `MyDocument` manages a separate background process (as an `NSTask`).  I want to make sure that the `NSTask` is terminated when its corresponding `MyDocument` closes or when the whole application quits.

For the latter, I make the document observe `NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification.`  For the former, I override the `close` method:

```
-(void)close {
    // Cleanup code here
    [super close];
}
```

(Incidentally, I can't put cleanup code in the `dealloc` method since the project is GC'd.)

The problem is this: If I open a `MyDocument`, make unsaved changes and then press cmd-Q, the `close` method is called *twice*.  From the debugger, the call chain is:
`[MyDocument close]` calls `[NSDocument close]`, which calls `[NSWindowController _windowDidClose]`, which calls `[MyDocument close]` again.  (After that call, the application quits).

Is this expected behavior?  If so, is there a better way to release document-specific resources?  Or should I just make `close` safe to run multiple times?

Comment: Interesting. This behaviour (receiving `-close` more than once) doesn’t seem to be documented. I think your suggestion of making `-close` safe to run multiple times is a good one.

Comment: In fact, you’re not the first to think of it: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/240166-nsdocument-close-method-calls-itself.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've seen a post to the cocoadev mailing list saying that this is normal behaviour for the frameworks at the moment (but that it might change in future). You should make your `-close` method robust enough to handle multiple calls since no guarantee is made by AppKit that it will be called only once.

I don't believe you need care about `NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification`, since if I understand correctly, tasks will automatically be terminated when your app is too. Furthermore, if you support sudden termination, your app can be killed without notice/notification anyway.